# Are Vegito super saiyan blue kaioken and Canba base form even?

Tags: dragon-ball-manga, dragon-ball-heroes

Why Canba transformed in chapter 3 of Dragon Ball Heroes into Golden Oozaru? Was he supposed to be weaker than Vegito super saiyan blue kaioken or was he supposed to be weaker? Some fans claims he was weaker, that wasnt what I got from the battle but perhaps it's portrayed differently in the manga.

Are Vegito super saiyan blue kaioken and Canba base form even?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fight, SSJB Vegito with Kaioken seems relative to Kanba in his Base form. I personally belive Kanba did have the edge over Vegito and would hence be stronger.

The second part of your question is why did he transform when he happened to be stronger.  The key point to note here is that Vegito and Kanba were relative in power. While Kanba might have won the battle if they were to continue fighting (Assuming Vegito didn't defuse), he would've been battle damaged and severely wounded during the course of the fight. When Kanba clearly has the level of power to outright overpower his opponent, it obviously made sense for him to transform into the Golden Oozaru.